# GAE Python - Receive incoming email on @mydomain.com address

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I am setting up a GAE app that triggers certain tasks by an email from the user. I've set up the app using the information on this page: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail. Everything works as expected, however, I would like to send the emails to a @mydomain.com email address, instead of a @myapp.appspotmail.com email address.

Currently I am using an automatic forward on the email address to get around this, however once this scales I expect to reach the daily limit on forwarded messages at some point (10.000 according to https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en).

Is there any way that I can integrate my app with the @mydomain.com email address to prevent this from happening? Or would you know another solution for this issue?

Comment: A few months ago we investigated the possibility to connect your own domain (@mydomain.com) and, unfortunately, we could not find anything. You can use a web service like this: http://dyn.com/email/dyn-email-forward/ or this https://web.easydns.com/Email_Forwarding.php or use "normal" server - f.examp. Google Cloud Computing - with own software. Chosen solution depends on your dns/server configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately that doesn't sound very promising. Did you also look into the possibility of putting the email address in a group under your own domain with a @mydomain address? Technically that seems to work, however I'm unclear if those emails are counted as automatically forwarded messages...

Comment: I don't know. I have other clue: https://support.google.com/a/answer/175745?rd=1 - maybe this will work, I don't try this.

Comment: I'm trying to implement an automatic forwarding from my Google Apps mail to my AppEngine app address, but how do I confirm the forwarding address? It sends a code, but AppEngine strips all html information from the received message so I can't access the confirmation code! How did you guys do it?

Comment: I did this by creating a group and add the app address there. Then you don't need the confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As LA_ mentioned, SendGrid offers a webhook for this. I ended up using MailGun, which has a similar functionality and calls a HTTP POST to my app whenever an email comes in on my @mydomain.com address.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you should check recently implemented GAE integration with [SendGrid](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendgrid), I haven't used it myself (use the same solution you've described with email forwarding), but looks like it can help.

Comment: I'll check that out, thanks! Will post here if it proves to be useful.